# estimating and expected value of date of birth

Tags: probability

The class is 30 people, all born in the same year. Calculate the probability,
that we all are born on different days, we assume that the number of days in a year is 366 (this estimate number). Calculate the expected value of the number of people who will be "lonely birthday". To best estimate the likelihood that these will be of less than 20.

Firstly, I would like pay attention to expected value. When You accept it I'll try other "things".

Let $X_i = 1$ - i-th day is birthday of exactly one person
$X_i=0$ - i-th day is birthday of $0$ or $> 1$ people.
$X$ - the number of days (number of people) such that exact one person has birthday.
$ X = X_1+\dots +X_{ 366} $
$EX = EX_1 +\dots +EX_{366}$
$EX_i = P(X_i=1)=(1-\frac{1}{365})\cdot\left(1-\frac{2}{365}\right)\cdot.... \cdot (1-\frac{28}{365}) $
$EX = 366 * EX_i =(1-\frac{1}{365})\cdot\left(1-\frac{2}{365}\right)\cdot.... \cdot (1-\frac{28}{365}) ~= 360 $
I computed (correctly?) expectec number of days that exactly one person has birthday - ok ?
How to compute expected number of pepole ?

Comment: It is too little - read up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem - for thirty people the probability of no pairs is about 30%

Comment: I edited, look again please

Comment: What value do you use for $EX_i$? (using you own calculationshould we see $EX_i=0.3190314625$, therefore $EX=116.7655153$ ... please recheck.

Comment: I edited st post